# Create Splashscreen for Android with XAML file (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

I have a project where you start with a login screen, generated with help of XAML. Before that i load an activity that holds my splash screen. Of course the activity can just load a AXML file in my SetContentView() method, therefor the splash screen is generated with AXML.

I want to place on both, login and splash screen, two icons. The exact positioning of these is rather difficult, if I want them to be on the same place to avoid jumping while changing splash to login screen.

My question now, is there a possibility to load the splash screen also with a through XAML?

Best regards, Manuela

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to have 2 splash screen at the beginning of the app, am I right? If yes, I do one sample that you can take look:

Firstly, you need to create three activities, one is MainActivity, another is Activity1, another is Activity2.

MainActivity:

```
[Activity(Label = "@string/app_name")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{     
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);         
    }
}
```

Activity1:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 3000; // 3 sec.
        timer.AutoReset = false; // Do not reset the timer after it's elapsed
        timer.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(Activity2));
        };
        timer.Start();

    }
}
```

Activity2:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/MyTheme.Splash1",NoHistory = true)]
public class Activity2 : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 3000; // 3 sec.
        timer.AutoReset = false; // Do not reset the timer after it's elapsed
        timer.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
        };
        timer.Start();

    }
}
```

splash_screen.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
  <color android:color="@color/splash_background"/>
 </item>
 <item>
   <bitmap
    android:src="@drawable/splash_logo"
    android:tileMode="disabled"
    android:gravity="center"/>
 </item>
```

splash_screen1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
   <color android:color="@color/splash_background"/>
 </item>
 <item>
   <bitmap
    android:src="@drawable/a9"
    android:tileMode="disabled"
    android:gravity="center"/>
 </item>
```

[image]